# How to convert numbers in a list into decimal and octal?

Tags: python

I need to convert some numbers from a list which I made into decimal and octal. The list works and so does the conversion. But I cannot get the conversion to work on the list.

```
print ("Welcome to Python binary convertor!")
print ("When you wish to stop entering numbers press x")
filename = "binarylist.txt"

numlist = []
num = input("Enter a binary number:")
while num !="x":
    numlist.append(num)
    num = input("Enter a binary number:")
def menu():
    print ("Your options are:")
    print ("     1. Convert Binary to Decimal")
    print ("     2. Convert Binary to Octal")
    print (" ")
    return int(input("Choose an option"))
loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        result = int(input("Enter a binary number"), 2)
        print (result)
    elif choice == 2:
            result = int(input("Enter a binary number"), 8)
            print (result)
    else:
                print ("Error:Invalid choice  ")
                loop=0
```

Comment: Look into the `oct`, `bin`, and `hex` functions, and try mapping them to a list. E.g., `map(oct(numlist))`.

Comment: Aside - use booleans (True/False) for, well, boolean checks. This isn't C, we try to avoid trash like that! Also, instead of `loop=0` consider a `while True:...break` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, the `base` argument for `int` is only for converting the string to an integer, not formatting. So in both cases above with bases, the base should be 2.

Since this is a homework question, take this away- in most cases, the machine doesn't know nor care what the base of an integer in memory was originally. It's irrelevant*, because memory physically represents these things in base 2. Base typically becomes relevant on interfacing with a human.

So, `int('101',2)` will decode the string as the integer value 5. To encode 5 in a different base, you need to do some string formatting yourself. An easy solution involves dividing the number by the base, then taking the answer as the most significant digit. Then dividing the remainder by the the base, then taking the answer as the next significant digit, etc.

*Some caveats for scientific computing, blah blah.

EDIT:

Yes, as @mlefavor points out there are built-ins for this, but consider that might not be what your prof is looking for ;) Besides, they don't work in the general case!

Comment: Thank you all. I found this very helpful. Keep up the good work. Assignment done and handed in in time!!!!